# Merged two dataframe columns with lists in order of lists

Tags: python, performance, pandas, processing-efficiency

I'm trying to merge/concatenate two columns where both have related, but separate text data delimited by "|" in addition to replacing certain names with "" and replace the | with '\n'.

For example, the original data may be:

```
    First Names            Last Names
0   Jim|James|Tim          Simth|Jacobs|Turner
1   Mickey|Mini            Mouse|Mouse
2   Mike|Billy|Natasha     Mills|McGill|Tsaka
```

If I want to merge/concatenate to derive Full Names and remove entries tied to "Smith" the final df should look like:

```
    First Names            Last Names            Full Names
0   Jim|James|Tim          Simth|Jacobs|Turner   James Jacobs\nTim Turner
1   Mickey|Mini            Mouse|Mouse           Mickey Mouse\nMini Mouse
2   Mike|Billy|Natasha     Mills|McGill|Tsaka    Mike Mills\nBilly McGill\nNatasha Tsaka
```

My current approach so far has been:

```
def parse_merge(df, col1, col2, splitter, new_col, list_to_exclude):

    orig_order = pd.Series(list(df.index)).rename('index')

    col1_df = pd.concat([orig_order, df[col1], df[col1].str.split(splitter, expand=True)], axis = 1)
    col2_df = pd.concat([orig_order, df[col2], df[col2].str.split(splitter, expand=True)], axis = 1)

    col1_melt = pd.melt(col1_df, id_vars=['index', col1], var_name='count')
    col2_melt = pd.melt(col2_df, id_vars=['index', col2], var_name='count')

    col2_melt['value'] = '(' + col2_melt['value'].astype(str) + ')'
    col2_melt = col2_melt.rename(columns={'value':'value2'})

    melted_merge = pd.concat([col1_melt, col2_melt['value2']], axis = 1 )

    if len(list_to_exclude) > 0:
         list_map = map(re.escape, list_to_exclude)

    melted_merge.ix[melted_merge['value2'].str.contains('|'.join(list_map)), ['value', 'value2']] = ''

    melted_merge[new_col] = melted_merge['value'] + " " + melted_merge['value2']
```

if I call:

```
parse_merge(names, 'First Names', 'Last Names', 'Full Names', ['Smith'])
```

The data becomes:

```
    Index   First Names        count    value            value2        Full Names
0   0       Jim|James|Tim      0        Jim              Smith         ''
1   1       Mickey|Mini        0        Mickey           Mouse         Mickey Mouse
2   2       Mike|Billy|Natasha 0        Mike             Mills         Mike Mills
```

Just not sure how to finish this out without any loops or if there is a more efficient / totally different approach.

Thanks for all the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a ***lot*** of comprehension

```
l = df.values.tolist()

['|'.join(n)
 for n in [[' '.join(z)
 for z in zip(*[s.split('|')
 for s in r]) if z[1] != 'Smith']
 for r in l]]

['James Jacobs|Tim Turner',
 'Mickey Mouse|Mini Mouse',
 'Mike Mills|Billy McGill|Natasha Tsaka']
```

---

```
l = df.values.tolist()

df['Full Names'] = [
     '|'.join(n)
     for n in [[' '.join(z)
     for z in zip(*[s.split('|')
     for s in r]) if z[1] != 'Smith']
     for r in l]]

df
```

[image]

---

word play aside, this is pretty snappy over sample data

[image]

---

***longer explanation***

```
l

[['Jim|James|Tim', 'Simth|Jacobs|Turner'],
 ['Mickey|Mini', 'Mouse|Mouse'],
 ['Mike|Billy|Natasha', 'Mills|McGill|Tsaka']]
```

- `l` is a list of lists.  I will make extensive use of list comprehensions and iterables.
- Each sub-list consists of 2 strings that I will split and zip together.
- The result of the split will be a "list" of tuples consisting of `(first, last)` names.  I'll use `if z[1] != 'Smith'` to filter out the smiths.

  - BTW, in this line you could use `z[1] not in list_of_names`
- I'll then use `' '.join` (that's actually a function) to combine each tuple to `first last`
- I'll then use another `'|'.join` to combine the sub-list of `first last` to `first1 last1|first2 last2`... so on and so forth

The reason why this is quicker is because comprehensions have been optimized to a great extent.  The other solutions are using `apply` which is a generic looping structure that can only leverage fast looping under special circumstances (someone who knows more, please correct me if I'm wrong).  Using `lambda` is definitely not one of those circumstnces.

Comment: Can you explain how this is so efficient and what exactly is it doing?

I can understand the first answer more or less (the "combin_names" approach by AlexG - but this is beyond me.

Apologies for my limited knowledge.

Comment: @wingsoficarus116 updated with something resembling an explanation

Answer (score 4):

Here is a condensed solution using `pd.DataFrame.apply` and some of python's nice built-in features:

```
def combine_names(row):

    pairs = list(zip(row[0].split('|'), row[1].split('|')))
    return '\n'.join([' '.join(p) for p in pairs if p[1] != 'Simth'])

df['Full Name'] = df.apply(combine_names, axis=1)
```

Comment: Nice solution @AlexG

Comment: Appreciate the solution!

How would I generalize this to be applicable to a dataframe with n columns where I simply wanted to add a column consisting of two columns merged as such?

Also, I'm not too familiar with .apply - can I pass arguments into combine_names? It would be ideal to pass a list of names to skip instead of just 'Smith' as that was an example.

Comment: You could code a list of names directly into the `combine_names ` function, but it must only take one argument. The argument passed is the row (assuming axis is set to 1). You could also call it like this: `df[['First Names', 'Last Names']].apply(combine_names, axis=1)` if you have more than just those two columns. Coming back to your first point, you could change: `if p[1] != 'Simth'` to something like this: `if p[1] not in ['Simth', 'John', 'King']`

Comment: I've worked around this by embedding the combine_names function in another function which creates a separate dataframe for combine_names to work on and then concats to the original df. 

Many thanks, very clever!

Answer (score 3):

I really like [@AlexG's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41579676/5741205) - please use it.

Here is my attempt to create a creative one-liner solution - it's absolutely perverse, so it should NOT be used - it's just for fun:

```
In [78]: df
Out[78]:
          First Names           Last Names
0       Jim|James|Tim  Simth|Jacobs|Turner
1         Mickey|Mini          Mouse|Mouse
2  Mike|Billy|Natasha   Mills|McGill|Tsaka

In [79]: df['Full Names'] = \
    ...: (df.stack()
    ...:    .str.split(r'\|', expand=True)
    ...:    .unstack(level=1)
    ...:    .groupby(level=0, axis=1)
    ...:    .apply(lambda x: x.add(' ').sum(axis=1).str.strip())
    ...:    .replace([r'\w+\s+Simth'], [np.nan], regex=True)
    ...:    .apply(lambda x: x.dropna().str.cat(sep='\n'), axis=1)
    ...: )
    ...:

In [80]: df
Out[80]:
          First Names           Last Names                               Full Names
0       Jim|James|Tim  Simth|Jacobs|Turner                 James Jacobs\nTim Turner
1         Mickey|Mini          Mouse|Mouse                 Mickey Mouse\nMini Mouse
2  Mike|Billy|Natasha   Mills|McGill|Tsaka  Mike Mills\nBilly McGill\nNatasha Tsaka
```